# iOS Apps Use Regular Lightning Cable: How?

Tags: ios, mfi

The latest update to Touchable app uses the **regular** USB-lightning cable to send and receive MIDI data (see [here](http://www.djtechtools.com/2014/12/09/touchable-3-turn-ios-devices-into-usb-controllers/)). How is this possible? Does this mean they are an MFi developer?

(I have read through the [MFi FAQ](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-1) but this case seems to not be covered)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are a MFi certified company. To develop an accessory that uses either the official Apple 30-pin connector or Lightning connector you have to be a part of the MFi program.